# Android development with Hyper-V on

Tags: android, docker, hyper-v

So I see some issues on Stack Overflow, saying that I need to turn off Hyper-V to get the Android emulator to run. However, I also have Docker for Windows installed, which requires Hyper-V to function. What is the best way to resolve this?

Is it possible to get the Android emulator to work on Intel HAXM while leaving Hyper-V alone for Docker?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the Android emulator part of this question, but in case this is not solvable you could instead use **Docker Toolbox** which runs without Hyper-V (but Virtualbox instead).

This is a legacy solution, but actually recommended by Docker documentation in case your system does not fulfill the requirements, e.g. for Windows 10 Home users ([Quote](https://web.archive.org/web/20181122161755/https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/): "Note: If your system does not meet the requirements to run Docker for Windows, you can install Docker Toolbox, which uses Oracle Virtual Box instead of Hyper-V.").

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hyper-V for accelerating the Android emulator instead of HAXM. That way you can use docker as well. I do the same.
Probably you are just missing "Windows Hypervisor Platform" from the Windows Features. Make sure it is enabled too.

For further information see: [Hardware acceleration for emulator performance (Hyper-V & HAXM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows)

Answer (score 0):

There's been some changes to Hyper-V in Windows that allows Android emulation to work with Hyper-V, as mentioned here:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/